# Getting TabLayout Fragment View instance as null on Date change in parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

On Selecting date from Date picker in parent activity of TabLayout making fragment view instance  null.

Below is the date picker method, after date selection I'm calling Fragment interface for upating fragment values **getCollectionListData()**. In which recycler view instance is getting null.

```
  private void showDatePicker() {
    Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(mDateTV.getText().toString());
        currDate.setTime(date);
        selectedYear = currDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        selectedmonth = currDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        selectedDate = currDate.get(Calendar.DATE);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DatePickerTheme, (DatePicker datePicker, int ofYear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) -> {
        selectedYear = ofYear;
        selectedmonth = monthOfYear;
        selectedDate = dayOfMonth;
        mDateTV.setText(selectedDate + "/" + (selectedmonth + 1) + "/" + selectedYear);
      
        mCollectionListFragment.getCollectionListData();

    }, selectedYear, selectedmonth, selectedDate);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
    Date result = cal.getTime();
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(result.getTime());
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Interface method in 1st Fragment.

```
 @Override
    public void getCollectionListData() {
        //listUpdated();
        mCollectionListRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Getting mCollectionListRecyclerView as null.

**Error:
NUll Pointer Exception on  mCollectionListRecyclerView.**

Comment: Insufficient code to analyze the problem. Adding the error message also would help to analyze better.

Comment: Consider not using `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` since those classes are troublesome and outdated. See if you can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).

Answer (score 1):

Take current fragment instance and call the fragment method.

```
Fragment childFragment = (Fragment) mViewPagerDetailsAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager,mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

if (childFragment != null) {
   ((MyChildFragment) childFragment).updateView();
}
```